# Call a function inside another function

Tags: javascript, node.js

am new to node.js

what i want is to call `shedule.schedulejobs` inside another function.
the following code is for updating some data in to db.i want to call the schedulejob after updatingthe details to database.how it is possible.

```
    exports.saveJobs = function (jobsCollection, context) {
      console.log(utils.httpBody(context.req));
      var record = utils.httpBody(context.req);  
      var id =record.id;
      var date =record.date;
      jobsCollection.update({ id: record.id}, { $set: record}, { upsert: true }, function (err, result) {
         if (!err) return context.sendJson([], 404);
// i need to call the schedule jobs after performing updation to db
                 schedule.scheduleJob(date, function (id) {
     });
     });

    }
```

schedule job function

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(id){
            return function(){
            console.log("inside----------")
            console.log(id)
            };

            }(id));
```

Comment: Can you call it in the callback that you have? `function (err, result) { schedule.scheduleJob(date, function (id) {}); if (!err) return context.sendJson([], 404); }`

Comment: but i tried that way it is not working

Comment: Why didn't you put in your post that you tried this? Note that I put the invocation before you do return.. Different thatn your example

Comment: `if (err) return context.sendJson([], 404);` instead of `if (!err)` -- if there is an error, stop. Otherwise, continue?